# Google Analytics EasyTracker v2 configuration

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I there a way I can configure `EasyTracker (v2)` without using xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  However, you can do it all in java if you don't use EasyTracker

```
Analytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
Tracker tracker = analytics.getTracker("UA-EXAMPLE");
tracker.setWhateverPropertiesYoudLike();
```

The XML file for EasyTracker is pretty straightforward though, just add a file containing this to res/values/analytics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-CHANGE-THIS</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Comment: EasyTracker has features I like (like tracking the time spent in each activity, track request sent on background thread, etc). I tried to create a Tracker like you suggested and set it as the default tracker, But EasyTracker keeps looking its config in the xml files.

Comment: yeah, you're going to have to manage a lot yourself if you don't use EasyTracker but it can all be done.  Probably easier to just make the xml file.

Comment: I having trouble using the xml file because I use aapt rename-manifest-package trick when I build my APKs.
Lets say my package name is "com.myapp". In the build process I change the package name to "com.myapp.dev". Because EasyTracker looks for its config under "com.myapp" it will not find it.

Comment: You could just copy in a different analytics.xml for each project with your build script.

Comment: Probably too late, but there is a setResourcePackageName function in Easytracke v3, which should help with package name problem

Comment: @shtolik I checked latest libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar from SDK/extras/google/ and EasyTracker doesn't have method setResourcePackageName() :-(

Comment: I reply myself setResoucePackage() is in GoogleAnalyticsServicesAndroid_3.01.zip from here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources